# How to ban bad wifi extender by his MAC address

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, ssid

Somebody made an unauthorized wifi extender, which has the same SSID than the network I connect, but is crappy, slow, unreliable, and rarely works.

The only way I can connect to internet, is to the original wifi router.

I use software like netsetman, to pick the right wifi, but it frequently fails and connects to the wrong one.

There is any way I can ban my PC from connecting to the wrong wifi by his MAC address?

I'm asking how to block my PC from connecting to the mac address of the extender.

I use windows 7 64b

Answer (score 2):

By far and away, the easiest and most reliable way to solve this is to change the SSID on your router to a very different SSID. There is no practical way for stopping a laptop from searching for a SSID where it happens to be. Just change your router here.

If you have other routers (extenders) with your SSID, change these as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to ban by MAC address.

This varies by device and operating system, but should be found in advanced settings.  This will make your device refuse to communicate directly with the extender in question.  (It will communicate with devices using that extender indirectly through any other Access Point.)

If you have the option you should change the SSID of your access point instead, as another user pointed out.